# Plotting JSON Data in Thingsboard Dashboard

Tags: json, dashboard, thingsboard, telemetry

I have a device and am publishing some nested telemetry to it similar to the following payload:

```
{ "results": { "job": "0009834", "partNumber": "thing-01", "snum": "00001", "voltage": 5.01, "current": 0.02 } }
```

The actual data is a bit more complex, but this should get my point across.  Is it possible to access the JSON attributes in the dashboard widgets for plotting or timeseries tables?  For example, plotting the historical values of results.voltage.